# Is possible to know from MS Windows OS if dTPM or fTPM is used?

Tags: windows, tpm, ftpm

Is possible to know from MS Windows OS, if OS uses discrete TMP chip (dTPM) or fTPM (Intel PTT, AMD fTPM) without going to BIOS or peeking inside the computer case?

E.g. when I open `tpm.msc` I see *Manufacturer Name: IFX* and *Specification version 2.0* only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check it via Powershell:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "Root\CIMv2\Security\MicrosoftTpm" -Class Win32_Tpm
```

I then googled ManufacturerId & ManufacturerVersionInfo and I could see that its a dTPM. Hope this helps.

Comment: Using `tpmtool getdeviceinformation` I see also `TPM Manufacturer Full Name` (but no `ManufacturerVersionInfo` unfortunately).

Comment: Probably this list of certified dTPMs may help https://trustedcomputinggroup.org/membership/certification/tpm-certified-products/

Answer (score 0):

IFX is Infineon.  Your TPM is not manufactured by Intel or AMD, so it's definitely not a "firmware" version, part of the CPU.  I suppose it's possible that you've got an "integrated" TPM, inside the CPU package, but I don't think that AMD or Intel ever made an "integrated" multi-die CPU package with an IFX die inside the package.

So, since your TPM is made by Infineon, I'd say that it's a "discrete" TPM.

Comment: You mean discrete not integrated. An integrated TPM isn’t a thing…

Comment: @Ramhound Microsoft disagrees with you: their discussion specifically names the three connection types. Does such a device exist in the PC space? Dunno. Perhaps Microsoft is describing a real thing in a real device. I note that AMD have used a multi-die architecture, and that they use a separate ARM core for TrustZone.

Comment: I need some general advice, `IFX` is just an example. E.g. some list of manufacturer names which mean it's fTMP or dTPM definitely. Otherwise I can Google for model as the other answer https://superuser.com/a/1829877/441634 suggests. See also the comments under that answer.